# How can you use Spring DeleteMapping with HTML-form or etc?

Tags: html, spring, mapping, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to use DeleteMapping in the Spring-Controller-Class:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
private void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Integer id)
{
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

I want to read in a id in html and delete the employee.
How can I use HTML to perform this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a form, a browser will only send methods `GET` and `POST`.  If you want to send a `DELETE`, you have 2 options.

1. Use Javascript/AJAX.  You can set the http method on a AJAX request and the browser will obey this.
2. Fake a `DELETE` using the [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-rest-method-conversion).  By putting a hidden field in your form, Spring will fake turning this request into a `DELETE` and call the correct endpoint.